# Is it possible to change iphone application settings from program?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to change the application's settings menu from the program. For example if I have a list of options the user chooses from in the settings menu, is it possible to load those options from a JSON string, rather than specify them when creating the application settings menu?

Answer (score 0):

No the settings will be created with the bundled settings plist file. The only way for you to change them programmatically is by using the NSUSerDefaults while your app is running.

Comment: oh ok. Can I get the selected title of a multi-value option? Right now I am only able to get the value.